# Using plyr to join two massive dataframes on two columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a very large dataframe that I need join to another dataframe on two columns.  I've been using merge to accomplish ir, but R runs out of memory the larger the tables get.  Is there a similar solution using dplyr or plyr? I hear they require substantially less memory to accomplish.  I know how to use the join function in plyr generally, what I am struggling with is joining by two columns.  The merge synatx I've been using is below:

```
Correlation_Table <- merge(Correlation_Table, inter, by.x = c(1,2), by.y = c(1,2), all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)
```

So for example if I have the following two dataframes:

```
> head(df1)
  x y         z          a
1 1 2 429.57410  43.746670
2 2 3 717.98184 524.288886
3 3 4 601.66938 640.245469
4 4 5  87.41476 318.964765
5 5 6 586.22234 196.759991
6 6 7 619.82194   3.308136
> head(df2)
   b  c        d
1  5  8 152.2855
2  6  9 191.5406
3  7 10 197.0520
4  8 11 175.4209
5  9 12 157.6239
6 10 13 136.3286
```

Where columns x and y of df1 are dimensions, while columns b and c of df2 are also dimensions and the other columns are measures.  My goal here is create a new dataframe of all three measures where records of df1.x and df1.y match df2.a and df2.b.

Is this possible using plyr?

Comment: You could check `full_join` from `dplyr`

Comment: I was just reading about full_join.  How do you specify which columns you want to join using full_join?  From the examples I've seen it doesn't look like you can.

Comment: There is a `by` argument

Comment: But how do I join via two columns in each each tbale.  In merge I can say by.x = c(1,2) and by.y = c(1,2).  What is the equivalent syntax using plyr?

Comment: Sorry about that I'll edit my original question

Comment: `full_join` will do the join on both columns, but they need the same names.

Comment: @jraab you can specify `by(c('a'='b', 'd'='e')` etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try

```
library(dplyr)
res1 <- full_join(df1, df2, by=c('x'='b', 'y'='c'))
```

According to `?full_join`

> by: a character vector of variables to join by.  If ‘NULL’, the
>             default, ‘join’ will do a natural join, using all variables
>             with common names across the two tables. A message lists the
>             variables so that you can check they're right. To join by different variables on x and y use a named vector.
>             For example, ‘by = c("a" = "b")’ will match ‘x.a’ to ‘y.b’.

and compare the results with

```
res2 <-  merge(df1, df2, by.x = c(1,2), by.y = c(1,2),
                           all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)
```

NOTE: The order of rows will be different

Comment: Could I do it by column indices rather than names?

Comment: @Ben I think it will not work here.  Why do you need indices instead of names?  Indices can be a bit non-specific when compared to names.

Comment: Just out of curiosity.